# Display out of stock products on specific category - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the woocommerce / inventory menu settings to hide all of the "out of stock" products from category listings.

But there are some products them i want to display in certain categorys even is the stock is 0.
Is there a function that can override the upper "main switch" in certain categorys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I coudnt find it before, but here is the solution regarding to businessbloomer:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items', 'bbloomer_hide_out_of_stock_exception_category' );
 
function bbloomer_hide_out_of_stock_exception_category( $hide ) {
   if ( is_product_category( 'specific-category' ) ) {
      $hide = 'no';
   }   
   return $hide;
}
```

Comment: Not working as of 06.22, btw